# Crashing: storyboardWithName:

Tags: ios, uistoryboard

Using the following method to get storyboard instance:

```
UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"storyboardName" bundle:nil];
```

I have noted that "If no storyboard resource file matching name exists, an exception is thrown with description: Could not find a storyboard named 'XXXXXX' in bundle....". I know it cannot be too careful to deal with the method.

My question is that is there any way to catch the exception and handle it manually.
Any directions?

Comment: show your storyboardname in file inspector

Comment: This is a constant that should be correct all the time, but if you are extra mega careful, maybe can use `@try`, `@catch`, `@finally`

Comment: @MuruganandhamK Thanks for the response, but i am afraid it`a common problem, not just in my storyboard ：）

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
NSString *sbName = @"storyboardName";
UIStoryboard *sb;
@try {
     sb = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:sbName bundle:nil];
}@catch (NSException *exception) {
     [self warnMissingStoryBoard:sbName];
     //handle here...
     return;
}
//use sb here...
```

Comment: I have put that into practice, and it works fine, no more crashes! Cheers！!@Tom,@Tj3n

Answer (score 1):

```
UIStoryboard *st;
@try{
st = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"XXXXXX" bundle:nil];
}@catch (NSException *exception)
{
NSLog (@"%@",[exception description]);
return;

}
```

In this case if the storyboardWithName:@"XXXXXX" does not exist, then the code will go into the catch block where we can do the necessary handling manually. I have just logged the description of the exception. We can do any processing in that block without the code crashing

Comment: In this case if the storyboardWithName:@"XXXXXX" does not exist, then the code will go into the catch block where we can do the necessary handling manually. I have just logged the description of the exception. We can do any processing in that block without the code crashing.

Comment: You should put the explanation in your answer. Edit your answer.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion.

Comment: @Wezly Although the adopted answer is easy to understand, but you were right, it will never be harmful to add some explanation.

Comment: @NikhilGupta Thanks for giving the response.